# Add beverages to the Help Center

Tags: feature-request

There seems to be a consensus here that preparing beverages (tea, coffee, cocktails, etc.) is on-topic here, and that it's included in ["Cooking & food preparation methods"](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). However, by the common, non-technical meanings of the terms, beverages are not "food", and preparing them is not "cooking".

I suggest changing that to be clearer. We could either changing it to something like "Cooking & food preparation methods, including for beverages" or alternatively add another bullet point for beverages.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a copy we can all edit on. I've put in one of your suggestions to start with.

Note that I reordered the bullet points - they're closer to being in order of popularity, and they also flow a little better.

---

If you have a question about:

- Cooking & food preparation methods, including beverages
- Recipe comprehension, improvement, and repair
- Food handling and storage
- Ingredient selection and use
- Kitchen equipment

...then you've come to the right place - we want to help you!

Comment: I don't object to you putting a copy of this as a community wiki and we can review/implement revisions, but it's buried in a rather specific meta question and therefore not very discoverable. I'm not sure it'll be much use in this context.

Comment: @Aaronut I just figured that, given the number of people who come to meta, it was unlikely that we'd get enough answers and votes to matter. I can delete it and just post the individual line, if you think that's better.